# How to change column size depending up on total numbers of bubble, in chart.js for bubble chart?

Tags: angularjs, charts, bubble-chart, chart.js2, angular-chart

I am trying to display about 200+ bubbles in one chart, where 150+ bubbles are concentrated in one range and the rest of 50 bubbles are in 3 columns. I want to change the columns size as per the bubbles count.
see the image: [image]

so red dot should be in big span and do not override each other. please help me out in this.